# Internet Explorer not displaying some selected characters

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9

I am using IE for getting some list of data into web page.

I want to display the string "`ECM&apos;s for DTC&apos;s. - CFC`" but on web page it is changed into "`ECM's for DTC's. - CFC`"

Anyone have some idea on this? I checked the XML code it is showing like this:

```
nameStrID=\"E000000B7E\"/>\r\n\t\t<param
    value=\"ECM&amp;apos;s for DTC&amp;apos;s. - CFC Code: 211\"
```

I am using IE-9

Comment: The obvious problem is that it's been double-encoded with HTML entities. You should have `&apos;` for apostrophes which is the HTML/XML entity for `'`, but you've done a second level of encoding for some reason. Beyond that, you haven't provided anything like enough code or examples to really see what you're trying to do or what the problem is.

Comment: I am unable to paste code here also its getting double encoded ECM& apos;s for DTC& apos;s. - CFC

I kept space here to display correctly

Comment: In SO, use the backtick character to mark inline code so it gets displayed properly.

Comment: IN mozilla its displaying correctly
Is it possible to make ``&apos;`` display in IE

Comment: Sorry Spudley for not giving the entire code here.
Actually code is complex and I dont have good knowledge on this coding so I aam unable to give details